# Cannot edit comments on Stack Overflow Android app

Tags: feature-request

I was answering a question on Stack Overflow with the Android app. I happened to notice that I could not edit the comment I made on a question. When I added another comment using the website, I could edit the latter comment, but I had no option to edit the previous one. Then, when I checked the latter comment on the Android App, there was no option to edit the comment for either comments. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Yeah I know that

Comment: Usually, you will get an option to edit when you long-press on it. Note that comments cannot be edited anymore after 5 mins.